# Magento 2.3.6 Product Page Layout

Tags: magento2

I want to change the layout of the Product Page in Magento 2.

I want 3 equal columns and then to move the cart and price contents into the 3rd column.

so the layout would be

Image | Short Descroption and Title | and then price, cart and available addons if chosen. I have attached a picture as an example.

can someone tell me what file(s) I need to change?

[image]

rob.

Answer (score 0):

Making layout 3 column

Override Magento_Catalog layout catalog_product_view in your theme and change the `layout` attribute of `<page>` from `1column` to `3columns`

you have to make layout updates like `<move>` 'remove' to get you desired design

Answer (score 0):

In your theme extend magento's catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<theme_dir>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

In your custom catalog_product_view.xml file, create a 3rd container for the 3rd column e.g.

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="new-pdp-third-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="new-pdp-third-container" after="product.info.media">
<!-- add your custom blocks here -->
</<container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Use CSS to style and align the 3 containers: `product.info.main, product.info.media and new-pdp-third-container`

Then reorder / move blocks and them to the 3rd container. eg.

```
<move element="product.price.final" destination="new-pdp-third-container" after="-" />
```

Comment: Hi there. thanks for the help.

Ive tried doing the above, and Im just getting a white screen of errors. Im guessing I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Would you be willing to help further? I can pay, not a lot as I'm poor but I can pay something.

Comment: Can you share what you have in your custom catalog_product_view.xml file?